# Is there a quick way to automock react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I have a large amount of react component that require a simple mock version.

Currently for each component I have to create a new mock folder then create a file for that component and then a new simplified version of the component.

```
├── models
│   ├── __mocks__
│   │   └── componentA.js
│   │   └── componentB.js
│   │   └── componentC.js
│   └── componentA.js
│   └── componentB.js
│   └── componentC.js
```

Each of my mocked files just looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const ComponentA = ({
}) => (
  <div>
    Mocked ComponentA
  </div>
);
export default ComponentA;
```

It results in a lot of extra work and repeated code.

Is there a way to use the Jest automock tool to automatically implement the above.

I tried using the following but it return a babel error:

```
const ReactCMock = (name) => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: (props) => (
    <div className={name}>
      {name}
    </div>
  ),
});

jest.mock('./componentA', ReactCMock('Component A'));
```

Error: `` babel-plugin-jest-hoist: The second argument of `jest.mock` must be an inline function. ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining `MockReactC` (see [the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64092579#comment113337772_64093147)) using a `function` declaration so it gets hoisted before the `jest.mock()` call, and wrap the call to `MockReactC()` in an arrow function:

```
function MockReactC(name) {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: (props) => (
      <div className={name}>
        {name}
      </div>
    ),
  };
}

jest.mock('./componentA', () => MockReactC('Component A'));
```

Comment: A wise use of function hoisting. Should be MockReactC because Jest restricts variable names in jest.mock factory.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Starting to think jest has too much magic...

Comment: Great thanks! The mock name and using `function` instead of `() => {}` did the trick. Only issue is the component is called `default` in the snapshots. I can change this by defining the default component outside of the return statement but I cannot set it to match name.

Comment: @sam you can use `default: function NameYouWant (props) { return ( ... ); }`

Comment: That doesn't work if I want to pass the name variable as the display name. I found a workaround which is to define the function separately but inside MockReactC and the edit its display name. i.e. `MockedDefault = (props) => ...` then `MockedDefault.displayName = name`

Comment: @sam glad you found what you wanted. There is another way perhaps less readable, but I believe `default: { [name]: (props) => ( ... ) }[name]` also works.

Answer (score 1):

Mocked component can be identified with conventional `data-testid` attribute used by React Testing library instead of `className`. Since component modules can potentially contain named exports, the helper can provide this option:

```
const mockReactComp = (name, namedExports) => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: (props) => (
    <div data-testid={name}>
      {name}
    </div>
  ),
  ...namedExports
});
```

The limitation of `jest.mock` is that the helper should be used inside factory function and have `mock` suffix.

A generic helper like this one can benefit from being shared between tests. This requires to place helper import the first. `jest.mock` is hoisted above imports:

```
import mockReactComp from './mock-react-comp';
// jest.mock('./componentA', ...) is hoisted here, mockReactComp is available
import ComponentA from './componentA';
jest.mock('./componentA', () => mockReactComp('ComponentA'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only mocking default export then something like this should work:

```
jest.mock('./componentA', () => (props) => (
    <div className={name}>
      {name}
    </div>
));
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work either. The first solution cannot reference the out of scope variable `ReactCMock` and the second solution gives the same jest hoist error

Comment: @sam use [`jest.doMock()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) instead of `jest.mock()`. The issue you're describing is unrelated to the one you've asked about here and has been answered.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts doMock isn't viable for top-level imports, it isn't hoisted and thus won't affect them.

Comment: @EstusFlask nothing in the question indicates it's a top-level import to begin with...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It's reasonable to assume that there are top-level imports because things are imported on top level in tests. `require`s are less comfortable to work with and occur on per need basis. It doesn't seem like a good idea to change coding habits just to be able to use doMock.